# Typo3 - assign tt_content.image to custom CType

Tags: image, upload, element, typo3

I have to offer the possibility to insert content elements like this:

Image 1 | Image 2 | Image 3 | List of links

So for this, I created a plugin of type CType.
This is what I set it to display in backend:

```
$TCA['tt_content']['types']['txproducts_pi1']['showitem'] = ''
        . '--palette--;LLL:EXT:cms/locallang_ttc.xml:palette.general;general, header, '
        . '--palette--;LLL:EXT:cms/locallang_ttc.xml:media;uploads, '
        . '--div--;LLL:EXT:cms/locallang_ttc.xml:tabs.images, image, '
        . '--div--;Files, media, '
        . '--div--;LLL:EXT:cms/locallang_ttc.xml:tabs.extended';
```

So the content element has 3 tabs: General, Images and Files.
I want to take advantage of CSS Styled Content and show the content element like this:

```
tt_content.txproducts_pi1.20 < tt_content.image.20
tt_content.txproducts_pi1.30 < tt_content.uploads.20
```

This is where I get an error: "#1314354065: Could not find row with uid "1" in table sys_file". 
"1" from the error message is in fact the value of the "image" field from tt_content.
If I comment this line, the uploads are shown.

Why doesn't this work with images also?

**EDIT:** The error message is wrong, because "1" is the number of images attached. If I attach another image, the error message is: #1314354065: Could not find row with uid "2" in table sys_file.

Comment: Can you verify whether the DB record exits (sys_file:1)?

Comment: No, it doesn't exist. I forgot to mention that "1" is in fact the number of images attached to the "image" field, not the actual file ID, so the error message is wrong.

Comment: Are you sure that you included the CSS from 6.1? Can you verify that all keys below `tt_content.image.20` also show up on `tt_content.txproducts_pi1.20` ?

Comment: Yes, in the main template I include "CSS Styled Content (css_styled_content)", not any other version. Also, the keys you mentioned are identical.

Comment: I have no further idea and would need to debug. Maybe we are overlooking something obvious.